# Command Shift Period (show hidden files) stop working

Tags: keyboard, mojave, shortcut

On my MacBook with OS Mojave, Command Shift Period (show hidden files) stop working. How to restore it??
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which folder did you try it on? that's a basic thing; so is restart. Did you bind it to some other shortcut in Keyboard preferences ?

Answer (score 1):

Just updated OS Mojave and it works again)

Now it's - 10.14.6 (18G103), previous was 10.14.1 maybe.

Comment: What was your previous version? What is the current version? 10.14.x , what is x?

Comment: Now it's - 10.14.6 (18G103), previous was 10.14.1 may be.